# Remove elements from Map based on records in another map

Tags: apex, class, map, delete

I have Map A which is a subset of Map B. Now I want to remove those elements of Map A from Map B. Is that possible to be done?

Comment: Please, give us wider example, probably with code providing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `remove()` method:

```
Map <String, String> mapOne = new Map <String, String>();
mapOne.put('key1', 'value1');
mapOne.put('key2', 'value2');
mapOne.put('key3', 'value3');
mapOne.put('key4', 'value4');

Map <String, String> mapTwo = new Map <String, String>();
mapTwo.put('key1', 'value1');
mapTwo.put('key2', 'value2');

for (String key : mapTwo.keySet())
{
    mapOne.remove(key);
}
```

Now `mapOne` will only contain `key3=>value3` and `key4=>value4`. This example is if the keys of the maps match.

If you want to remove elements from one map based on values from another, then instead of `keySet()` just use `values()`.

[Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm)

Answer (score 5):

A clear and efficient solution would be by using keySet() and removeAll() methods.

Explanation:

**map.keyset()** will return a reference to the set of keys of the respective map, enabling the interface to use set class methods. which in turn allows us to use the **removeAll()** method to remove all the keys from the map at once.

Example:

```
Map <String, String> mapOne = new Map <String, String>();
mapOne.put('key1', 'value1');
mapOne.put('key2', 'value2');
mapOne.put('key3', 'value3');
mapOne.put('key4', 'value4');

Map <String, String> mapTwo = new Map <String, String>();
mapTwo.put('key1', 'value1');
mapTwo.put('key2', 'value2');

System.debug(mapOne);
mapOne.keySet().removeAll(mapTwo.keyset()); // removing elements from map
System.debug(mapOne);
```

[image]

Comment: This should be marked as the best answer. No need for loops here!